# How to get QModelIndex to insert a new row in a QAbstractTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Model/View programming for the first time, I am using a table view along with a `QAbstractTableModel` and `QStyledItemDelegate` as I need combo boxes.
This is my model:

```
class STableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
    STableModel(int rows = 1, int columns = 1, QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                    int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
         int role = Qt::EditRole);

    bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
    bool insertColumns(int position, int columns, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
    bool removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
    bool removeColumns(int position, int columns, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());

   private:
    QList<QStringList> rowList;
    ComboBoxItemDelegate *myDelegate;
};
```

Here I am trying to add a new row in my model and application is crashing, I think it is crashing because of an invalid index.

```
   STableModel *model; = new STableModel(1, 1, this);
   QModelIndex index = model->index(1, 1, QModelIndex());
   model->insertRows(1, 4, index);
```

How can I get correct index here or guide me to add row using another approach. Thanks

Edit:

```
bool STableModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    int columns = columnCount();
    beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        QStringList items;
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column)
            items.append("");
        rowList.insert(position, items);
    }

    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does the crash occur in the insertRows() method? Please, post the implementation.

Comment: And by the way: you don't need to provide an index in the insertRows() method, if you are implementing just a "flat" table (without sub items).

Comment: Crash is occurring on line QModelIndex index = model->index(1, 1, QModelIndex()); or here if I try to use model->insertRows(1, 1, QModelIndex());

Answer (score 0):

The `model->index(1, 1, QModelIndex());` returns an invalid index because there is no index with coordinates [1, 1].
You can remove this line, you don't need the parent index for this table.

With the provided information, I can't say why the `index()` method crashes. It shouldn't, even if invalid row and column number is provided.

Comment: I need this index to pass it to insertRows() where beginInsertRows needs QModelIndex, first and last.

Comment: When inserting top-level rows, the parent index can (and should) be empty. So, put there just QModelndex(). What happens if you call the insertRows() method like this: model->insertRows(1, 4), without the third arument?

Comment: On using model->insertRows(1, 4) application is crashing again with message: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Does it crash in the beginInsertRows() method or somewhere else?

Comment: I observed that control is not going inside insertRows().

Comment: If it doesn't go into the insertRows(), where does it crash than?

Comment: just at this point model->insertRows(1, 4, QModelIndex()); and on this line if i use model->insertRows(1, 4), i tried debugging it but control isn't going inside insertRows().